# how to render (or pass) 2d array[][] to html?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have a node.js server, and it has an array[][] data by user's file input.

I want to pass it to html page by `res.render()`, Could you give me advice on how can I do that?

I did search similiar problem but usually they are about rendering array[], not an array[][].

my array[][] data is like this:

```
dataLogs[0] ={latitude:33.333,longitude:22.222},
dataLogs[1] ={latitude:33.344,longitude:22.255},
dataLogs[2] = {latitude:33.355,longitude:22.277}

(...)
```

I want to pass these dataLogs[][] to map html page, for making html mark these places.

I tried to use ejs & res.render(), but I think These are not enough.

```
const ejs = require("ejs");
const express = require('express'),
http = require('http'),
app = express(),
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

var dataLogs = have some 2d array data;

(...)

  app.get('/replay', (req,res) =>{

      res.render('drawLines.html',{dataLogs:dataLogs});

  });
```

This is `drawLines.html` page

```
var dataLogs = <%= dataLogs %>
(...)
var linePath = [
    new kakao.maps.LatLng(dataLogs[0].latitude, dataLogs[0].longitude),
    new kakao.maps.LatLng(dataLogs[1].latitude,  dataLogs[1].longitude),
    new kakao.maps.LatLng(dataLogs[2].latitude,  dataLogs[2].longitude ) 
];
//kakao is just kind of API for map interfaces
(...)
```

`dataLogs[x].latitude`, `longtiude` are not possible to read at this code.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: This is not a 2d array, it is an array of objects.

Comment: Try this: `<%= var dataLogs =  dataLogs =>`

Comment: I tried to change ```var dataLogs = <%= dataLogs %>``` to ``` <%= var dataLogs = dataLogs %> ``` but have error. It said unexpected token.